# android studio expandable bottom sheet with recycleview

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]
[image]

as you can see the bottom sheet is expandable when there is more than one line of the `recycleview`.
I want to implement the same thing in the profile page so that if posts are more than three lines then I can expand the bottom sheet, then I can scroll the `recycleview` (when the sheet is expanded).

my current xml:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/allPosts"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_behind_recycleview"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:elevation="1dp">


        <com.taimoorsikander.myapplication.Widgets.B_RecycleView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

^
it looks like the image I attached but it is not expandable yet.
is this possible in Android Studio? if yes, please help.

Answer (score 0):

In this tutorial they teach you how to set the Behaviour in the BottomSheetFragment,
take a look it's really helpful, there you will find how to set the Behaviour that you want with BottomSheetBehaviour.from(...)...

[Kotlin language](https://howtodoandroid.com/bottom-sheets-android/)

Basically you have to set the height(Ex: peekHeight = 50) you want than and set "false" to hide the bottomSheet and "true" to (isDraggable).

There is 2 ways of doing this declarative in the XML or programmatically, I'll show the first:

1º Your first layout needs to be CoordinatorLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2º The bottomSheetLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#81D4FA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Pay attention to this TAGS, which states the behavior and state of the BottomSheet:

> app:behavior_hideable="false"

> app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"

> app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"

> app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"

Comment: the problem is that this is the second tutorial I find on this topic and it is on Kotlin, I'm using java sadly.

Comment: BottomSheetBehaviour.from().apply{} doesn't work in java, I believe it must be modified a little but I don't know how.